# Column relative resize when text wraps on smaller screen IONIC HTML5

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework, alignment

[image: Aligned properly when screen size is large enough]

[image: Row alignment thrown off when screen size is small]

I am working on an Ionic based web-application. This page's layout is three separate column lists. When the screen size is too small, the middle column automatically resizes to wrap the text, and as a result, is not properly aligned with the two outer columns.

How can I ensure that the alignment adjusts for all screen sizes?

Comment: If you don't want to use `overflow ellipsis` you can also put a height with scroll for each element. (I know, its not good, but I think you have just those options for this problem, If you don't wanna change the with)

Comment: Is there no way to have the left/right columns also resize when the middle one does?

Comment: You can put a javascript code, every change on the table he changes the others tables based on the middle table. With pure css I think its no possible